# Race condition - multiple application instances using one database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scaling, race-condition, horizontal-scaling

I plan to scale up my Rails application to multiple instances, but they will still use the same database.  If two users end up using two different instances of the application, editing the same account, then this will definitely cause race conditions somewhere - What's the best way to prevent this given that this is a Rails application?

The only database related settings I know of allow specification of the actual servers IP. If a program could be a middle man somehow it would solve the problem... Otherwise the application instances will have to communicate with each other in some way right??

Unless there is a way to solve this using settings in Postgres...

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: here is a article you can read- https://www.leighhalliday.com/avoid-race-conditions-with-postgres-locks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to implement an **[optimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html)** strategy. Rails supports this out of the box. Writing a fully-fledged tutorial for this is out of the scope of a stackoverflow answer. Please find detailed instructions online.

The basics are: 
For each model you want to protect, you will need to add an integer column called **`lock_version`** to the model's database table. Plus in every form you will need to add a hidden field that carries this lock_version. And of course allow the lock_version param in the controller if you are using safe params.

Whenever you save a record and a lock_version is present, Rails will make sure that the lock_version matches the one in the database. If they don't match, this means that another update has occurred in the meantime and the current update fails with a `StaleObjectError`.

As a fallback strategy, I suggest you display a flash message to the user whose update was rejected. Also, render the same form they were filling in again, using the current values from the database (not the attempted inputs, since you want the user to reconsider if their changes were appropriate).

(You can implement the fallback strategy application wide by defining a `rescue_from` hook in your `ApplicationController`.)

HTH!

Comment: So every time you go to make an update, you get the current lock_version of the object with your request for it's current state, cool. thanks, I'll look into this

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by 'current' but sounds about right. Check it out and let me know how it works out for you!

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have said current. I understand that it's generated and then sent to the person requesting to make an update. then when the user sends the update, they send the lock version with it and if they don't match up the backend knows that someone else is in the middle of an update as well. Did I get that right?

I'll be implementing this in the future but I was just thinking of what to do when I get there. Thanks!

Comment: You got it right :) However, the lock_version is not generated but kept in the database. Every record has its own lock_version that will be incremented on every update.